# Fill a large range of cells with the same formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm printing formulas to 8000 rows and a set number of columns. I'm using two for loops to print the formulas on the columns. Although the code works, it takes very long to finish.

```
'N is a value that is supplied by the user and can be large
 For j = 1 To N                                               
     For Z = 50 To 8050                                               
 Cells(Z, j + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=3*R31C[0]*(R23C[0]/1000)*((R15C[-1]+RC1)/SQRT(3)/(v_RMT*1000)/cos_phi)^2"
     Next Z
Next j
```

Is there a faster way to perform this task?

Comment: You can write a formula to an entire range in one go: `MyRange.FormulaR1C1 = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Loop needed:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(50, 2),.Cells(8050,N+1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=3*R31C[0]*(R23C[0]/1000)*((R15C[-1]+RC1)/SQRT(3)/(v_RMT*1000)/cos_phi)^2"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, it works way faster! Now I'll implement throughout my code in other parts!